# Oracle function “TO_NUMBER” not supported in H2 database

Tags: h2

Function TO_NUMBER is in a [H2 roadmap](http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html) for 1.4.x as priority 2.
But in the last version 1.4.196 it's still not supported.
Can anyone tell me, in what version can I expect support for this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround, execute this SQL to create the function:

```
CREATE ALIAS TO_NUMBER AS $$
Long toNumber(String value) {
    return value == null ? null : Long.valueOf(value);
}
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Digulla provided [a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387581/1479414), but unfortunately it does not really cover all semantics of the Oracle's `to_number` function.

One of the corner cases is the ability to parse numbers like this `7E+8`. `Long.valueOf(value)` does not cope with that.

To be more close to the actual implementation, I suggest to use a slightly extended version of the suggested alias:

```
CREATE ALIAS TO_NUMBER AS '
@CODE
Long toNumber(String value) {
     return value == null ? null : Double.valueOf(value).longValue();
}
'
```